# MainWindow stays hidden if application is lunched under screensaver

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, .net-4.5

I have WPF app that is started by windows scheduler with next properties set:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
  Title="Updater" Width="1366" Height="768" WindowStyle="None" 
  ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
</Window>
```

Switching from screensaver shows application visible in TaskBar, but not on screen. Fixed that by changing label text every 1 sec to enforce refresh. Have tried other solutions like `InvalidateVisual`, `Show`, `Activate`, `PostMessage` `SWP_SHOWWINDOW` but nothing worked.

Edit: The only link have found is way back from 10 years ago "[There is no support for updating a Window that is hidden or minimized in the framework presently](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e974c849-90ea-4741-9a27-0ae4857bc3c2/wpf-update-ui-in-while-window-is-hidden?forum=wpf)."

Comment: is "run only when user is logged in" checked for the task?

Comment: yes, user is logged in

Answer (score 0):

i have suggestion for you to try: Try using the Topmost property of the window. This solved an issue i had a while back with the application not being visible on the desktop initially - maybe it will help you too.

So for me my window wasn't showing unless i did something like this:

```
        window.Show();
        window.Activate();
        window.Topmost = true;
        window.Topmost = false;
```

I'm not sure if this will solve your issue in any way, but i thought a suggestion couldn't hurt.

Cheers
Marian